# ggplot density plot produce unexpected result

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a question regarding density plots using ggplot. In order to make my problem clear I have created the following sample data:

```
DT2 <- data.table(Rating = c(1:19),
            Nndef = c(50, 30, 70, 70, 60, 40, 60, 30, 30, 10,
                      5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Now I want to graph a density plot of the number of Nndefs per rating category. Before I do this I copy each row by the number of Nndefs such that each rating catagory occurs Nndef times.

```
DT2 <- DT2[rep(1:.N,Nndef)]
```

Now this should do the trick:

```
ggplot(DT2, aes(x =Rating))+ theme_bw() +
geom_density(aes(x=Rating))
```

which gives me 
[image]

This is actually what I expect to happen using this data. However, consider this now

```
DT1 <- data.table(Rating = c(1:19),
            Nndef = c(460, 480, 1300, 2600, 5700, 4700, 9300, 10600, 7700, 8200,
                      6500, 6700, 5300, 4700, 2700, 1100, 1200, 400, 420))
DT1 <- DT1[rep(1:.N,Nndef)]
ggplot(DT1, aes(x =Rating))+ theme_bw() +
geom_density(aes(x=Rating))
```

which results in this
[image]

I am familiar with the `adjust` argument in `geom_density` but I am running a lot of these ggplots in a `for` loop. I want to obtain a smooth density plot (just like the first one using DT2) but not want to manually adjust each figure myself. In addition, I do not understand why it produces a kinky density distribution in the latter case and a reasonably accurate in the former case. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems like your data is discrete. Density plots are for continuous random variables. Perhaps you would be better served by a bar plot.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that it is for continuous random variables. However, I like the visualization of defaults in a density plot. I really prefer it by using `geom_density` unless of course this is not possible in an automated way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could limit the adjustment factor to a fraction of the number of unique values of 'x':

```
ggplot(DT1, aes(x =Rating))+ theme_bw() +
      geom_density(aes(x=Rating), adjust=length(unique(x))/10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, pretty obvious actually but couldn't come up with it.